# Javascript function in chrome makes black lines appear

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, audio

I'm using a javascript function to play a mp3 file when I click a button.

```
        var soundEmbed = null;
        function soundPlay(url) {
            if (soundEmbed)
               document.body.removeChild(soundEmbed);
            soundEmbed = document.createElement("embed");
            soundEmbed.setAttribute("src", "/snd/"+url+".mp3");
            soundEmbed.setAttribute("hidden", true);
            soundEmbed.setAttribute("autostart", true);
            document.body.appendChild(soundEmbed);
        }
```

In google chrome when I click the button, the sound plays but the scrollbar on the right turns into a black line and there is a thin strip of black on the top of the window to the left. On firefox and IE, it is fine, no black lines.

Anyone know what the problem is/how to fix it?

Also when i put a `soundEmbed.setAttribute("loop", true);` in there, it doesnt loop on chrome either, while it does with IE/firefox.

Comment: Have you tried `soundEmbed.setAttribute("style", "display: none");`?

Comment: Just tried then. Didn't work.

Comment: I just tested on my Chrome 14.0.835.109 beta-m, and I don't see any visual irregularities. Could you show us your HTML?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using the `<audio>` tag? This would give you programmatic control over playing, pausing, and other useful controls related to audio specifically.

Comment: If your browser is chrome. it should support the native `<audio>` tag, why not use audio instead of `embed`

Comment: Awesome, thats much easier then and no more black line. Does this work on previous versions of the main browsers? like ie 6,7,8 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest possible version of Google Chrome.